# Word for "the little chores" in life

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

I'm looking for a noun which roughly means "the little chores" in life, something similar to mundane tasks (such as fetching groceries, doing the laundry, etc), but a bit more generic than "errand". Preferably something that implies that the action could be repeated.

Comment: I would say that "mundane tasks" is the usual term for this in the US.

Comment: The word "chore" itself means a mundane job, an everyday task that a person needs to perform. Add *daily* and you reinforce the meaning, "(a) daily chore/s"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minutia** covers most of this. While it doesn't refer specifically to chores, it's often used to convey drudgery or triviality as in "the minutiae [plural] of daily life."

Webster's:

> a minute or minor detail —usually used in plural

Answer (score 1):

Consider [***the daily round***:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/the-daily-round)

> UK *old-fashioned*
>
> the tasks you have to do every day:
>
> *I get exhausted just by the daily round.*

(Definition and example from Cambridge Dictionaries Online.)

***Everyday tasks*** and ***daily to-do list*** are further possibilities.

Comment: I'd go for "daily chores/errands"

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Those are certainly possibilities, but the OP's question is asking for some different terms.

Answer (score 1):

A daily [routine](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Routine) suggests a a series of ordinary repeated actions: (from TFD)

> - A set of customary or unchanging and often mechanically performed activities or procedures:
>
>   - a routine of housework.